# Rails 3 Testing: How To Open The Browser When Testing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2, webrat

What is the name of the gem that lets you open the browser with the result in your request specS?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is called selenium :)

https://github.com/ryanb/selenium-on-rails